# minimal ms between "despgraph_update"?

Tags: python

i use `depsgraph_update_post` to update my particle position.
what is the easiest way to  limit the update to a minimal interval of let say 500ms ?

i tried to play with import datetime or time, by **surveying time.now(): storing it as a prop and do some deduction about how many ms passed** between updates

i did a second attempt by **launching a blender timer**

But i'm almost sure that there's an way easier way to do this within python am i right ?

Comment: Can you please explain what the actual problem is that you're trying to solve? What is triggering the event handler at such high frequency that you need to apply the limit? Could it be that a more specific callback through `msg_bus` may be useful?

Comment: It seem that bpy.mgbus is a better solution. But there’s not info abo it it anywhere, possible to make it persistent ?